# Highcart Set From and To when I start

Tags: highcharts

I would like to ask if is possible set "FROM" and "TO" in the highchars/Stock.

[image]

I am using YEAR, so I would like to load the year but in the Input FROM and TO set a value dynamically with number after a calculation.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

## 1.Update:

With:

```
var minDate = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(0)').val();
var maxDate = $('input.highcharts-range-selector:eq(1)').val();
```

I can get the date, but to set should be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateCurrent = new Date();

  events:{
                    load:function(){ 
                        this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
                        Date.UTC(2000, 0, 1), dateCurrent
                    );
                    }
                }
```

Just use setExtremes().